# Possible to add a vertical separator between Angular Material tabs?

Tags: angularjs, tabs, angular-material

A client is requiring us to add a vertical line in between our angular material tabs.  While this appears to be frowned upon, we cannot figure out how to accomplish this.
Here is an example: 
[Angular Material tabs](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/tabs)

We've tried the angular md-divider but this only appears to work for vertical lists that need a horizontal line.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can't you just tweak the css to add a border to the left sight and remove it on the first child?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be a mistake to add markup just for styling, in my opinion. I'd either use borders or pseudo-elements.

```
.md-tab {
  border-right: 1px solid red;
}
```

**[Demo 1](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JWyyBZ)**

```
.md-tab:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 3px;
  background: green;
}
```

**[Demo 2](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dvzzQw)**

To hide the last tab's border you could add a class using Angular's `$last` and target that (or add it manually if you're not using `ng-repeat`).

```
ng-class="{'last-tab-class': $last}"

.md-tab.last-tab-class {
  border-right: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

add custom style to `md-divider`

`<md-divider class="vertical-divider"></md-divider>`

```
.vertical-divider {
  border-top-width: 0;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  border-right-style: solid;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I tried that here and it did not work: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/perrVN